# Adding UIButtons for specific words in UITextView

Tags: uibutton, uilabel, uitextview, tvos

Imagine an app like Wikipedia for the Apple TV, where it has a block of text that contains information about a given topic. Some words or phrases in the text could be other available topics you could read. Therefore you need to make those words/phrases into focusable and clickable buttons.

On a web page it's really easy to do this with links, and it's easy to style the links to look different from the non-interactive text. On tvOS, it would be easy to apply attributes to ranges in the text using `NSAttributedString` where you can determine the start and end index of the phrases - that's not a problem.

My question is, how would you go about actually creating the focusable buttons for text that is in the text view? I was thinking about somehow determining the rect that surrounds each phrase, and adding invisible buttons on top of them, then when it becomes focused make it visible so the user knows it's active. I'm not convinced that's a good approach. Also allowing all buttons to be focusable as expected could be tricky.

Looking into this, others have recommended using a web view and showing that in the app because it's easy to make the buttons links inside a paragraph tag for example. But `UIWebView` isn't available for tvOS.

What's a good solution to this problem? It will need to allow the user to intuitively focus and navigate between the text buttons. In this specific case, we could assume the text view will not scroll, therefore a `UILabel` could be used instead of a `UITextView` if necessary.

Wikipedia on the web - need to map to Apple TV app:

[image: Wikipedia]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if adding multiple buttons is a good idea.

I would add an 'open' button at the bottom of the screen. Additionally you can use swipe left/right events to navigate from one phrase to another. The passphrase in scope can have a different color. The 'open' button will open the article of the current selected phrase.

Just an idea. Hope it's useful for you.